# Why doesn't RStudio clear its Global Environment when something goes wrong?

Tags: r, rstudio

Using R Version 4.0.2 and RStudio Version 1.3.1056

This is honestly one of the strangest features I've seen in RStudio, and I suppose there's probably a good reason for it to be there, but I'm currently not seeing it and I feel that it can lead to a lot of issues of misleading data.

Basically, to my understanding, when you create and open an R project in RStudio, RStudio creates a Session with a Global Environment.
Every time you run something, this is added to the Global Environment, I assume it's done as a cached value.

However, I've encountered situations where this feature leads to either:

1. Outdated/wrong values being shown in my tests.
2. Cases where a function stops working altogether after changing 1 piece of code, executing the new code, then undoing the change.
3. functions "bleeding into" other files without importing/sourcing them.

Case 1 and 2 obviously leads to a lot of issues while testing. If you try to run a test like

```
test <- someFunction()
test #to display the value of the test
```

If the code is correct, the test will execute and the results of `test` will be stored in the Global Environment.
However, if you then proceed to break the code and run the test again, since `test` already has a value stored in Global Environment, that **old** value will print, even though the function failed and thus didn't return anything. Of course if you go above on the console feed, you might run into a line after `test <- someFunction()` saying "someFunction failed for X reason", but I still think it's both pretty misleading and not very intuitive. Sometimes the result of a function is really large and it's complicated to scroll all the way up the console to see if the code exited with an error, whereas other IDEs would simply immediately tell you at the end of the console that the code failed, and not print the old and outdated value.

Example: Running the proper code.
[image: Running the proper code]

Running the code after having changed `is.na` to the non-existent `is.not.na`.
Notice how it's still printing the old value belonging to the previous version of the function.
[image: Running the code after changing is.na to the non-existent is.not.na]

The third case can also lead to misleading scenarios.
If you execute a function in any file within your session, the function is stored in the Global Environment. This allows you to call the function from any other file, even if you haven't added a `source` statement at the top to load the file containing that function.
Once again this can lead to cases where you inadvertently change/add a new function on file B without running it, then try to invoke the function from file A and you get unexpected results because you were actually invoking the old/outdated function, and the Global Environment has no idea about the changes to the old one or the new function.

All of these issues are rather easy to fix, but I think that's a bit beyond the point. Why is this a feature in general? Why isn't the Global Environment emptied upon errors in execution? I know that you can manually empty the GE whenever you want, but it seems odd to me that the IDE doesn't do it on its own, or, to my knowledge, that it doesn't provide you with an option for it to do it.

I can imagine that it provides some benefit at runtime, but is it really that significant that it can justify these behaviors?

Comment: You could file an issue with RStudio on their github for a feature request if you like https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio. But they are just doing what would happen when you run R interactively (which is how the language was originally designed). You don't want one bad command to wipe out everything you've done previously. I'm not sure your suggestion really makes sense for most users. Perhaps you would prefer an Rmarkdown file. Those are always run in a new session when you build them.

Comment: I can see how that is a good reason for the GE to not be cleared upon errors, however, I guess it would still be nice to give the option to users, or at the very least, to include a final line in the console indicating the code finished with errors/Warning that the values displayed correspond to those in the GE, like other IDEs do.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256291/make-execution-stop-on-error-in-rstudio-interactive-r-session